# Is it possible to execute a sub-command from a Gnome Shell launcher?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

I've got an alias set up to launch my text editor in a way that keeps it local to the specific desktop I'm working on in Gnome Shell:

```
alias geany="geany --socket-file=/tmp/geany-sock-$(xprop -root _NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP | awk '{print $3}') ${1+"$@"}"
```

I'd like to emulate this with the actual Gnome Shell launcher.  As it stands, I have the launcher command set to:

```
geany --socket-file=/tmp/geany-sock-$(xprop -root _NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP | awk '{print $3}') %F
```

Which will point to the open Geany session in the current window if one is already open, but it won't launch a new session.  I'll get a spinner, and then it just quits rather than launching the app.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell parameter and variable expansion in `.desktop` files is [neither supported nor documented](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/1.1/ar01s06.html). The usual workaround is (like Avlmd said) to create a shell script and point the `.desktop` file to that executable.

When it comes to launching applications from dash, `gnome-shell` defaults to [activating](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GApplication.html#g-application-activate) the application instead of launching it if another instance is already running (as long as you don't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> to actually launch a new instance).
`gnome-shell` behavior can be altered via shell extensions, so in your particular case an extension overriding `onActivate` from `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/appDisplay.js`   should do what you want:

- Create extension folder:

`mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/geany-launcher@blahblah.blah`

- Add these two files inside:

`metadata.json`:

```js
{
    "shell-version": ["3.6.3.1"], 
    "uuid": "geany-launcher@blahblah.blah", 
    "name": "Geany Launcher", 
    "description": "Fire up new window if no instance on current workspace"
}
```

`extension.js`:

```js
const Clutter = imports.gi.Clutter;
const Shell = imports.gi.Shell;
const Main = imports.ui.main;
const AppDisplay = imports.ui.appDisplay;

var _onActivateOriginal = null;

function  _onActivate(event) {
        this.emit('launching');
        let modifiers = event.get_state();
        let cTRL = Clutter.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK;
        let rUN = Shell.AppState.RUNNING;
        let crtW = global.screen.get_active_workspace();
        if (this._onActivateOverride) {
            this._onActivateOverride(event);
        } else {
            if (this.app.get_id() == "geany.desktop") {
                if (this.app.state == rUN && ((modifiers & cTRL) || !this.app.is_on_workspace(crtW))) {
                    this.app.open_new_window(-1);
                } else {
                    this.app.activate();
                    } 
            } else {
                if (modifiers & cTRL && this.app.state == rUN) {
                    this.app.open_new_window(-1);
                } else {
                    this.app.activate();
                    }
                }
            }
        Main.overview.hide();
}

function init() {
  _onActivateOriginal = AppDisplay.AppWellIcon.prototype._onActivate;
}

function enable() {
  AppDisplay.AppWellIcon.prototype._onActivate = _onActivate;
}

function disable() {
  AppDisplay.AppWellIcon.prototype._onActivate = _onActivateOriginal;
}
```

- Restart shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then enable the extension with `gnome-tweak-tool` (you might need to restart the shell one more time to enable the extension).

This works with `gnome-shell-3.6.3.1`, if you have another version edit `metadata.json` and change this line to reflect your shell version (no guarantee it would work with older shell versions like 3.4.x or future versions like 3.8.x):

```js
"shell-version": ["3.6.3.1"],
```

---

Note that the extension only overrides shell behavior, if you (double) click files in `Nautilus`to open them with `Geany` it would still activate the primary window on another desktop so you will also have to resort to the shell script trick to get a consistent behavior: open a new window only if no instance is on current desktop otherwise activate the existing one. I don't have `xprop` installed but this works on my system:

- Create a new executable somewhere in my $PATH (like `/usr/local/bin/djinni`):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

geany --socket-file /tmp/geany-sock-$(xdotool get_desktop) ${1+"$@"}
```

- Point the launcher (`/usr/share/applications/geany.desktop`) to the newly created script:

  `Exec=djinni %F`

Comment: Thank you! This is apparently what I've been looking for.  The piece I added is in my `.bashrc` I've aliased geany to point to my new executable (`alias geany=/usr/local/bin/geany2`), which appears to be more reliable for some reason than aliasing to the original -`--socket-file` command.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is to save your command to ~/bin/geany:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
cat > ~/bin/geany
/usr/bin/geany --socket-file=/tmp/geany-sock-$(xprop -root _NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP | awk '{print $3}') $1
^d
chmod 755 ~/bin/geany
```

executable and make .desktop launcher like this: `/home/$USER/bin/geany %F`.