# Keyboard shortcut to open a new terminal if one doesn't exist on this desktop. Otherwise, focus the current one

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome-terminal, xdotool

I would like to create a keyboard shortcut that will open a new terminal window only if none exists on the current desktop. Otherwise, the currently existing one will be focused. I just upgraded from Fedora 24 to Fedora 25. Before upgrading, I had the following script bound to `ctrl-alt-t`:

```
desktop="$(xdotool get_desktop)" # Get number of current desktop

#Check if there is an open terminal on the current desktop. 
output="$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class --desktop $desktop gnome-terminal)" 

if [[ -n "$output" ]] 
then xdotool windowactivate $output #If there is, then move focus to it. 
else gnome-terminal &  #Otherwise, open a new terminal. 
fi
```

However, it seems that the update has broken the script, and it no longer runs properly; a new terminal is always opened, regardless of the presence of an existing one. As a test, I tried running this one liner `desktop="$(xdotool get_desktop)" && for i in $(xdotool search --desktop $desktop --class ".*"); do xdotool getwindowname $i; done`. Unsurprisingly, its output never includes the name of an existing terminal window. It seems that the problem is that `xdotool` no longer recognizes the gnome-terminal in Fedora 25, and as a result the above script will always create a new terminal.

**EDIT:**
Also, running `xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname` in terminal returns:

```
xdo_get_focused_window_sane failed (code=1)
xdo_focus_window reported an error
```

So it really seems that xdotool can no longer recognize `gnome-terminal`

Comment: This kind of stuff is better handled via gnome-shell extensions imo, [see this related (almost duplicate) question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/67955)...

Comment: Note, you are probably using gnome with wayland, which does not support xdotool. You can switch to X11 gnome, but this option will probably be removed in later releases.

Comment: @meuh Yup, switching to "Gnome with Xorg" did the trick.